# c++. Strange constructor declaration?

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters, constructor, parent

I use MonkSVG lib. Here is an example of code:

[link](https://github.com/micahpearlman/MonkSVG/blob/master/src/openvg/mkOpenVG_SVG.cpp)

Here is a part of code:

```
OpenVG_SVGHandler::OpenVG_SVGHandler()
    :   ISVGHandler()
    ,   _mode( kGroupParseMode )
    ,   _current_group( &_root_group ) 
    ,   _blackBackFill( 0 )
    ,   _batch( 0 )
    ,   _use_opacity( 1 )
    ,   _has_transparent_colors( false )
```

As I understand the first one - `ISVGHandler()` - means the calling of the parent constructor without params.

So:

- what do the other params mean?
- `_current_group( &_root_group )` means I need to pass an additional parameter to it, isn't it?
- For example, is there any difference between `_batch(0)` and `batch = 0;`?
- has an order any influence?

Comment: This should be treated in any introductory C++ book or tutorial

Comment: Do a search for "initializer list".

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Initialization lists are a Good Thing.  This coding style, however, is an **abomination**.

Comment: Coding style looks okay to me.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  Oh, it's horrid.  Don't tell me -- you're an emacs guy. ;)

Comment: @JohnDibling: No, Sublime Text.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley:  Hmm, never heard of that one, I'll check it out.

Comment: the only thing I don't like in this code style is this library is for iOS/OSX projects only. It means a possibilty of using C++ and Objective-C together in one file. But in Ojbective-C white spaces are used as operators too. So I don't like extra whitespaces in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OpenVG_SVGHandler::OpenVG_SVGHandler()
    :   ISVGHandler()
{
    _mod = kGroupParseMode;
    _current_group = &_root_group;
    _blackBackFill = 0;
    _batch = 0;
    _use_opacity = 1;
    _has_transparent_colors = false;
}
```

=> shortcut =>

```
OpenVG_SVGHandler::OpenVG_SVGHandler()
    :   ISVGHandler()
    ,   _mode( kGroupParseMode )
    ,   _current_group( &_root_group ) 
    ,   _blackBackFill( 0 )
    ,   _batch( 0 )
    ,   _use_opacity( 1 )
    ,   _has_transparent_colors( false )
{
}
```

order has some influance

```
Class::Class()
    :  b(a),    // b == 10, 0, or random value ?? Compiller usually raises warrning
       a(10)
{
}
```

Comment: Members will be initialized in the order in which they appear in the class body.  The order in which they appear in the initialization list is irrelevant to the compiler, though good practice dictates that the order should be the same as that of the class body.  In your example, if `a` appears before `b` in the definition of `Class`, the initialization will work correctly, and `b` will be correctly initialized with `a`.

Comment: -1:  An initialization list is not a *shortcut* for assignments within the constructor body.  The implication is that they are the same thing -- but they aren't.

Comment: This answer is incomplete but no one can post new answers so I accept it.